# Setting up gRPC Proxies for HLF Operator Operations Console

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-besu

I've hit a roadblock recently while working on setting up the Fabric console. While I've managed to successfully deploy the console, I'm stuck at the gRPC proxies part. Despite my efforts to dive into the documentation, I'm finding it difficult.

I'm unsure where to add the properties related to gRPC proxies. Do these properties belong within the same deployment configuration as the Fabric console, or do I need to create a separate deployment specifically for the proxy? I've added the screenshot for the same.

I'm unable to create json for importing orderers and peers in the console due to the absence of gRPC proxies.

[Error for grpc proxies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lewu9.png)

The documentation for gRPC Proxies:
[Hlf Operator Documetation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaZLE.png)

But there is no mention of where does one add these properties to ? Do I need to create seperate deployments for all peers ? I've been stuck at this for long now. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I got this solved. You need to add the properties in the crds itself. Inspect the code for crds and add the grpc property.